# Sort NSDictionaries in NSMutableArray by NSDate

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, nsdate

I have a NSMutableArray with dictionaries, all of the dict's contain a NSDate is form of NSString with key 'Date'. I want to sort the NSDictionaries by the Dates. So for example i have the following state of the array:

```
Dict
   Date
      20.06.1996 23:30
Dict
   Date
      04.10.2011 19:00
Dict
   Date
      20.06.1956 23:39
```

And I want to sort it, so that it looks like this:

```
Dict
   Date
      20.06.1956 23:39
Dict
   Date
      20.06.1996 23:30
Dict
   Date
      04.10.2011 19:00
```

I have already experimented with NSSortDescriptor, but without success...

Update:

I have managed to sort the dates, but I came to this problem: In the dicts there is not only dates, also other objects, and what my code does is it only switches the date values between the dicts, instead of switching the complete dicts around. With this, the other values in the dicts get assigned a wrong date, which is very bad. Can anybody help me? Heres my code:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"savedData.daf"];
NSMutableArray *d = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:path];



for (int ii = 0; ii < [d count]; ii++) {
    NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    if (is24h) {
        [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm"];
    }
    else {
        [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm a"];
    }
    [dateFormatter setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
    NSDate *dat = [dateFormatter dateFromString:[[d valueForKey:@"Date"] objectAtIndex:ii]];
    NSMutableDictionary *newDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    NSDictionary *oldDict = (NSDictionary *)[d objectAtIndex:ii];
    [newDict addEntriesFromDictionary:oldDict];
    [newDict setObject:dat forKey:@"Date"];
    [d replaceObjectAtIndex:ii withObject:newDict];
    [newDict release];
}


NSSortDescriptor *sorter = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"Date" ascending:YES];
NSArray *sorters = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sorter, nil];
[sorter release];
NSMutableArray *sorted = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[d sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sorters]];
[sorters release];
NSLog(@"%@",sorted);
for (int ii = 0; ii < [sorted count]; ii++) {
    NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    if (is24h) {
        [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm"];
    }
    else {
        [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm a"];
    }
    [dateFormatter setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
    NSString *sr = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[[sorted valueForKey:@"Date"] objectAtIndex:ii]];
    NSMutableDictionary *newDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    NSDictionary *oldDict = (NSDictionary *)[d objectAtIndex:ii];
    [newDict addEntriesFromDictionary:oldDict];
    [newDict setObject:sr forKey:@"Date"];
    [sorted replaceObjectAtIndex:ii withObject:newDict];
    [newDict release];
}
NSLog(@"before: %@"
      ""
      "after: %@",d,sorted);
[sorted writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
```

Comment: You should post the code you couldn't make to work.

Comment: I'm confused. Do they contain NSDates or NSStrings? You say both, but an object can't be simultaneously an NSDate and an NSString.

Comment: It is NSStrings, sorry for that!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are many ways to do this, one would be to use NSDate objects instead of NSStrings (or NSStrings formatted according to ISO 8601, so that the lexicographic sort would match the desired sorting). Then you could do:

```
NSSortDescriptor *descriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"Date" 
                                                             ascending:YES];
[array sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:descriptor]];
```

Or, if you can't (or don't want to) change your data, you can always sort using a block:

```
[array sortUsingComparator:^(id dict1, id dict2) {
    NSDate *date1 = // create NSDate from dict1's Date;
    NSDate *date2 = // create NSDate from dict2's Date;
    return [date1 compare:date2];
}];
```

Of course this would probably be slower than the first approach since you'll usually end up creating more than *n* NSDate objects.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it really helped me, I ran through another problem, it is explained in the updated question, please check it out, and try to help me :)

Comment: A lot of unnecessary code aside, replacing `[d objectAtIndex:ii]` with `[sorted objectAtIndex:ii]` should fix your problem.

Comment: cheers! That was it! And what about the unnecessary code ? :)

Comment: Your code is unnecessarily complex. You don't need to copy NSMutableDictionaries (they're *mutable*), you don't need to convert dates back and forth, etc.

Comment: But i need to convert the strings to dates to sort them, and then I need them to be converted back to Strings, because my whole app is only working with the strings!

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of options, one is to put NSDate objects in the dictionary.

One problem with comparing the strings is that you can 't just do a string compare because the year is not in the most significant potion of the string.

So, you will need to write a comparison method to use with:

```
- (NSArray *)sortedArrayUsingComparator:(NSComparator)cmptr
```

or perhaps:

```
- (NSArray *)sortedArrayUsingFunction:(NSInteger (*)(id, id, void *))comparator context:(void *)context
```

The comparator will need to handle the `dd.mm.yyyy hh:mm` string format.

Other options include adding another dictionary key with an NSDate representation and sorting on that.

Comment: Could you give me some more code please, I can't figure it out like this!