# How to sort "key" and "value" in NSMutableDictionary by NSDate?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sorting, nsdate, nsmutabledictionary

I have a `NSMutableDictionary`, that contains contact names (`NSString`'s) and the dates (`NSDate`'s).  The names are the `keys`.  **How do I sort the names by date created?**

I assume I have to create a `NSMutableArray` of the dates, then sort it somehow.  **But then how do I get the names for the dates?  How do I even sort `NSDate`'s?**

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe this can help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7628808/1758762

Comment: You can't sort an NSDictionary.  You must copy the contents to an NSArray or some such to sort them.

Comment: [NSDictionary keys sorted by value numerically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1620001/nsdictionary-keys-sorted-by-value-numerically) will provide the solution.

Answer (score 4):

Try the following code if the dict contains NSString in date format:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"your date format"];

NSArray *sortedKeys = [yourDictionary  keysSortedByValueUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(NSString *obj1, NSString *obj2)
{
    NSDate *date1 = [dateFormatter dateFromString:obj1];
    NSDate *date2 = [dateFormatter dateFromString:obj2];
    return [date1 compare:date2];
}];
```

The sortedKeys will contain the sorted names.

If the dictionary contains actual NSDate objects then:

```
NSArray *sortedKeys = [yourDictionary  keysSortedByValueUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(NSDate *obj1, NSDate *obj2)
{
   return [obj1 compare:obj2];
}];
```

Comment: The second code section worked!  Thanks a million!

Comment: If you found the answer, mark it as accepted ;)

Comment: Aaa, the beautiful down vote without a comment explaining the reason of down vote.

Comment: Thanks for the second part @ZachLucas !

Answer (score 0):

You can use `[myDictionary keysSortedByValueUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];`